# The fundamental group of a wedge sum applying Van Kampen 's theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology

I need to compute the fundamental group of the wedge sum $\mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^2$. I want to find two open sets $U$ and $V$ such that their intersection is a simply connected space so I could apply Seifert Van Kampen theorem. Any ideas please?

Comment: Note, you don't need the intersection of the two open sets to be simply connected to apply van Kampen's theorem, you only need it to be path-connected.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese True but with a simply connected extension you get a free product rather than an amalgamated product, which is a bit nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a point from the $S^1$ away from $X$ to give $U$
(not the basepoint of course) and just take a point from the $S^2$ away from $X$ to give $V$
(not the basepoint of course). Then $U\cap V$ is a wedge sum of $\Bbb R^1$
and $\Bbb R^2$ which is easily shrunk down to the basepoint.

Comment: The fundamental group i am looking for is Z right?

Comment: It's the free product of $\pi_1(S^1)$ and $\pi_1(S^2)$. Is that $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Of course not but i am asking because in this link https://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/MATH212/algebriki%20topologia-new.pdf page 46 claims this

Comment: @user391120 That's all Greek to me! (sorry, couldn't resist!). Do you know what $\pi_1(S^1)$ and $\pi_1(S^2)$ are?

Comment: the fundamental group of first is the set of the integers and for the second {0} or not? I meant the second shape in page 46 .I am sorry for all this trouble and many thanks for your help

Comment: They are $\Bbb Z$ and $0$ indeed!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown no I think it is $\mathbb{Z}$. You have $\mathbb{Z}*\{e\}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Consider the presentation of this free product, it is just $\{a, e:\varnothing\}$, where $a$ is the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $e$ is the generator of $\{e\}$, $\varnothing$ means there is not relation modding out, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a free group. Then $a$ must generate $e$, so $e$ is redundant.